# How to send data from an android application (client) to a python flask (backend) remote server

Tags: android, python, flask, server, client

First of all bear with me as I'm new to both android applications and python flask.

I found sample code (java) on the web, which sends json data from an android application to a php web page (http://hmkcode.com/android-send-json-data-to-server/). What I want to do is to use this sample android code to send the data to a remote VPS server and use python flask as backend to receive and save the data .

As far as I understand the first thing that I have to replace is the php-address http://hmkcode.appspot.com/jsonservlet with my server's IP address (99.99.999.99) in the java code,

```
    switch(view.getId()){
        case R.id.btnPost:
            if(!validate())
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Enter some data!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                // call AsynTask to perform network operation on separate thread
                //new HttpAsyncTask().execute("http://hmkcode.appspot.com/jsonservlet");
                new HttpAsyncTask().execute(99.99.999.99);
        break;
    }
```

Then I have to add the python flask code which will receive the data.

Concerning flask I found the following code which might apply to my issue,
https://github.com/javierchavez/Android-with-flask-backend/blob/master/Backend/wsgi.py.

Thus my questions are :

**1st** Is it correct to only replace the php-address with my VPS IP address, or do I also have to add the path to the flask file in my remote's server home directory.

**2nd** what would be the actual flask code, which will receive the data from the application and save it to the remote server (as far as I understand the python flask file will be saved in the VPS's home directory)

**3rd** do I also have to take into consideration the password required to access my VPS remote server when modifying the android and flask code?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Answering to the first question, it is correct to only specify the IP if the action you want to perform is declared on the root ("/") route of the flask server, otherwise you have to append the path you specify in the *@app.route()* tag.

Comment: by that you mean that if the flask file is saved as `flask_wsgi.py` in the VPS's home directory then I can use `new HttpAsyncTask().execute(99.99.999.99)` but I have to specify also `@app.route(/ flask_wsgi)` inside the flask file?